# Background color over top of background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I'm trying to have my striped colored background with a narrow center single color background on top of it where some articles and photos will go.  I can't get the colored background to show up.  I don't see what is wrong with my code. I've tried making it in divs, I've tried doing a multiple background in the body css, etc.  Where do I put it?

I've also implemented a coded gallery which is giving me headaches.

CSS file

```
body {
        text-align: center;
        background: url("redstripebackground.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center top;
    }

#nav {
     font-family: Celtic Garamond the 2nd;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 14pt;
     width:1000px;
     margin:0 auto;
 }

#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

    #nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 25px 2px 25px;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FF0000;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 24px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        width:150px;
        z-index: 11;
    }

        #nav ul li a.active {
             background-color: #FFBF00;
        }

            #nav ul li a.active:hover {
                 background-color: #FFBF00;
            }

        #nav ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #FFBF00;
            color: #000000;
        }
#icon {
     font-family: Varsity Regular;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 50pt;
     width:1000px;
     margin:0 auto;
 }

#icon ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#icon ul li {
    float: left;
}

    #icon ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0px 25px 10px 25px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FF0000;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 60px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        width:150px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
        z-index: 11;
    }
    #icon ul li a.active {
         background-color: #FFBF00;
    }

    #icon ul li a.active:hover {
         background-color: #FFBF00;
    }

    #icon ul li a:hover {
        background-color: #FFBF00;
        color: #000000;
    }
```

Navigation bar file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerandBackground.css">
    </head>
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Club</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="icon">
    <ul>
           <li><a href="#">UCLC</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Home Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
</script>
     <style>
     body{
         width:1000px;
         margin:0 auto;
    }
    #cp_widget_63af049c-b69e-4e75-8019-da486b92eef5{
    width:900px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0px auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('Navbar.php'); ?>

    <div id="cp_widget_63af049c-b69e-4e75-8019-da486b92eef5">...</div><scripttype="text/javascript">
var cpo = []; cpo["_object"] ="cp_widget_63af049c-b69e-4e75-8019-da486b92eef5"; cpo["_fid"] = "AgNAf3ry4BXk";
var _cpmp = _cpmp || []; _cpmp.push(cpo);
(function() { var cp = document.createElement("script"); cp.type = "text/javascript";
cp.async = true; cp.src = "//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime/libasync.js";
var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
c.parentNode.insertBefore(cp, c); })(); </script><noscript>Powered by Cincopa <a href='http://www.cincopa.com/video-hosting'>Video Streaming Hosting</a> solution.<span>New Gallery 2014/7/25</span><span>height</span><span> 500</span><span>width</span><span> 958</span><span>camerasoftware</span><span> Paint.NET v3.5.11</span><span>originaldate</span><span> 1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM</span><span>height</span><span> 620</span><span>width</span><span> 1024</span><span>camerasoftware</span><span> Paint.NET v3.5.11</span><span>originaldate</span><span> 1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM</span><span>height</span><span> 500</span><span>width</span><span> 960</span><span>camerasoftware</span><span> Paint.NET v3.5.11</span><span>originaldate</span><span> 1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM</span><span>height</span><span> 500</span><span>width</span><span> 957</span><span>camerasoftware</span><span> Paint.NET v3.5.11</span><span>originaldate</span><span> 1/1/0001 6:00:00 AM</span></noscript>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I didn't know that John Stamos knew how to code.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your description of what you're trying to accomplish. Exactly which element should have a colored background? Also, you shouldn't be setting a width on your body. Leave that to Weight Watchers, not CSS ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna make a guess of what you need, according to what you say you want to do, you just need a page with a background image and a centered area that has color, right?

The HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">
        <p>My content, articles images and stuff</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The CSS

```
body{
  background: red url("redstripebackground.jpg") center top no-repeat fixed; /* style according to what you had in your stylesheet */
  background-size: cover;
}
#content{
  background: #fff; /* white background, replace with your color */
  margin: 20px auto; /* 20px for top and bottom, auto calculates the space, resulting in a horizontally centered div */
  padding: 10px 15px; /* space between your content and the edge of your white colored div  */
  width: 80%; /* width of the solid color */
}
```

In here you can see it working, without the image, of course.
http://jsfiddle.net/rafky/

The coded gallery will need a separated thread since is a completely different problem and we need more data of what should be doing and where it's going wrong.  (BTW, if you are including the navigation php you don't need to add the `head` or `body` tags)